# how to show these subspaces are nested and terminated?

Tags: linear-algebra

consider $A,B$ are $m\times n$ real matrices 
we define

$V_0:= \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V_{i+1}:= A^{-1}(BV_i)$

I need to show they are nested subspace and terminate.

What I mean by this is there exists limit of this subspaces say $V^*:=\cap_{i} V_i\neq \phi$ and $V^*=V_{k+i}=\dots=V_i\subseteq V_{i-1}\subseteq\dots\subseteq V_2\subseteq V_1\subseteq V_0$

am I correct?

and here is how I tried to show that $V_{i+1}\subseteq V_i$

suppose $x\in V_{i+1}\Rightarrow x\in A^{-1}(BV_i)\Rightarrow Ax\in BV_i$

so $B^{-1}(Ax)\in V_i$, then I am not getting how to proceed.

Thankx for helping.

Comment: What exactly is $A^{-1}$ if it is $m \times n$?

Comment: Okay $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m, A^{-1}S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: Ax\in S\}$ where $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Answer (score 2):

If your assuming $A$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, then to prove that the subspaces are nested you can use induction. Let us prove that the image of the linear map $A^{-1}B$, restricted to $V_i$, is contained in $V_i$ for all i. The base step of the induction is obvious. Suppose the statement is true for $i$ and let $x=A^{-1}By$ for some $y\in V_{i+1}$. I claim that $x\in V_{i+1}$. By definition of $V_{i+1}$, $y\in A^{-1}Bw$ for some $w\in V_i$. By the induction hypothesis, $y\in V_i$ and again by definition, $x\in V_{i+1}$.

Then nestedness follows simply from the fact that the image of a linear map is a vector space. Hence, the image of the linear map
$$A^{-1}B:V_i\to V_i$$
is a subspace of $V_i$ and $V_{i+1}\subset V_i$.

A simple dimension argument will give you stability after finitely many iterations.